# How can I assign values to TJSONValue using Delphi XE4 unit Data.DBXJSON?

Tags: json, delphi, pascal, delphi-xe4

How can I assign values to TJSONValue using Delphi XE4 unit Data.DBXJSON

```
var JSONValue: TJSONValue;
    JSONString: TJSONString;

JSONString := TJSONString.Create('Name');
JSONValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue('Jhon');
```

But JSONValue remains equal to nil

because I am making my JSON object in the following way

```
var lobj: TJSONObject;

lobj.AddPair('Nane', 'Jhon');

// but I want to use this version of AddPais
lobj.AddPair(const Str: TJSONString; const Val: TJSONValue):
```

Comment: `'Jhon'` is not valid JSON, so it makes sense that `ParseJSONValue('Jhon')` would return `nil`. `ParseJSONValue('{"Nane": "Jhon"}')` would return a `TJSONValue` pointing to a `TJSONObject`. `ParseJSONValue('"Jhon"')` should return a `TJSONValue` pointing to a `TJSONString`.

Comment: could you make an example code? @RemyLebeau

Comment: For what, exactly? Use the code you already have. Just fix your JSON input you are passing to `ParseJSONValue()`.